# Game objects wrong positioning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, transform, positioning

The objects are being set to out of the canvas
The objective of setting them is to show the user inventory with only the items that the user have
It's setting them active normally, and in the order that the user got it, but in wrong positioning
No error messages were sent
Before setting the positions array, i checked what were the positions in the scene to put it right on the array
But the objects are setting in the wrong place
I put this debug logs to try to see the problem
But it says the positions that i set
[image: Object Positions]
[image: Debug Logs]
[image: Apples Inpector][image: Double Speed Inspector][image: Super Force Inspector]
This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;

public class Filters
 : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Items")]
    public GameObject doubleSpeed;
    public GameObject doubleJump;
    public GameObject superForce;
    public GameObject noGravity;
    public GameObject noHit;
    public GameObject apple;
    private GameObject[] items;
    public int index = 0;
    public float[] position = new float[6] { -125.8f, -78.6f, -24.1f, 23.1f, 80.69913f, 36.3375f };
    private float x;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Player player = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
        Filter(doubleJump, player.doubleJumps);
        Filter(doubleSpeed, player.doubleSpeeds);
        Filter(superForce, player.superForces);
        Filter(noGravity, player.noGravitys);
        Filter(noHit, player.noHits);
        Filter(apple, player.apples);
        items = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Have");
        if(items.Length != 0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            {
                items[i].transform.position = new Vector3(position[i], 52.8f , 1f);
                items[i].SetActive(true);
                Debug.Log("Changed the position and set active new position:" + items[i].transform.position);
            }
        }
    }
    void Filter(GameObject item, int quantity)
    {
        if(quantity < 1)
        {
            item.SetActive(false);
            Debug.Log("less than 1");
        }
        else
        {
            item.SetActive(true);
            Debug.Log("set active");
            item.tag = "Have";
            Debug.Log("set the tag");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are they in the wrong place? Or just the numbers didn't match what you thought? Have you tried not setting them to centre

Comment: They are setting in the wrong place, i put a number and they are positioning in other.

Answer (score 1):

1. In general there is a difference between the **localPosition** - the position relative to the parent object and usually the one displayed in the Unity Inspector - and the absolute world space **position** you are setting in

   ```
   items[i].transform.position = new Vector3(position[i], 52.8f , 1f);
   ```
2. Further there is an even bigger difference when dealing with a `RectTransform`. What you see and edit in the Inspector is the [`RectTransform.anchoredPosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-anchoredPosition.html) which is relative to the parents `RectTransform` and additionally takes the `Anchors` and `Pivot` settings into account.

   So try this instead

   ```
   items[i].GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition3D = new Vector3(position[i], 52.8f , 1f);
   ```

`anchoredPosition3D` is basically the same as `anchoredPosition` but additionally allows to set the delta in the `Z` axis

---

In general for your usecase I would recommend to use a [`HorizontalLayoutGroup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-HorizontalLayoutGroup.html) and rather let the UI handle the placement itself. You would then simply use `SetActive` to hide and show items.